# Wrong working directory used when tagging Maven release

Tags: maven-2, bazaar, maven-release-plugin

When I run `release:prepare` on my Maven project, it fails when attempting the `scm-tag` phase.

My Maven project uses Bazaar for its SCM. My plugin versions are maven-release-plugin 2.0 and maven-scm-plugin 1.4

```
[INFO] EXECUTING: cmd.exe /X /C "bzr tag myproj-pathway-0.0.2"
[ERROR]  Not a branch: "D:/proj/".
```

The problem of course, is that the actual working directory/branch is `D:/proj/branch`; the parent is just a normal directory.

I assume the problem is with tagging since the modified POM is successfully checked in. How do I configure things so that tagging actually works correctly?

Comment: I don't know how to configure Maven to do this, but basically you need it to pass `-d d:/proj/branch` or `-d branch` to `bzr`.

Comment: Most of the information maven uses for this goal is in the scm section of your pom file. Can we see your pom.xml or at least the scm section of it?

Comment: try using the version 2.4 of the maven-release-plguin, it fixed a similar problem to me.